# calculate: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}dx$; find my mistake

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x
&=\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\Re\left(\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\Re\left(-i\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{\gamma(t)^{4}+\gamma a(t)^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}t\right) \end{aligned}$$

Now we have $2$ poles with the order of $2$ so:
$$
\text{Res}(f,-i)=(t+i)^{2}\frac{4x^{3}+2x}{(t-i)^{2}(t+i)^{2}}=\frac{4i-2i}{-4}\\
\text{Res}(f,i)=(t-i)^{2}\frac{4x^{3}+2x}{(t-i)^{2}(t+i)^{2}}=\frac{4i-2i}{-4}
$$
Therefore they cancel each out, so I get that the integral should be $0$.
Can someone spot my mistakes? and provide me solution?

2nd attempt:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\Re\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{(x\pm(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})(x\pm\sqrt[3]{-1})}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\\Re\left(\underset{R\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{(x\pm(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})(x\pm\sqrt[3]{-1})}\mathrm{d}x\right)=\\\Re\left(\underset{R\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\oint_{c}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{(x\pm(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})(x\pm\sqrt[3]{-1})}\mathrm{d}x}{2}\right)=\pi i(Res(f,\sqrt[3]{-1})+Res(f,-\sqrt[3]{-1}))\\Res(f,\sqrt[3]{-1}))=\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt[3]{-1}i}}{(\sqrt[3]{-1}+(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})((\sqrt[3]{-1}-(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}))(\sqrt[3]{-1})+\sqrt[3]{-1})}\\Res(f,-\sqrt[3]{-1}))=\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt[3]{-1}i}}{(\sqrt[-3]{-1}+(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})((\sqrt[-3]{-1}-(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}))(\sqrt[3]{-1})+-\sqrt[3]{-1})}\\\Re\left(\underset{R\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\oint_{c}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{(x\pm(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})(x\pm\sqrt[3]{-1})}\mathrm{d}x}{2}\right)=\pi i(\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt[3]{-1}i}}{(\sqrt[3]{-1}+(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})((\sqrt[3]{-1}-(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}))(\sqrt[3]{-1})+\sqrt[3]{-1})}+\frac{e^{2\pi\sqrt[3]{-1}i}}{(\sqrt[-3]{-1}+(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})((\sqrt[-3]{-1}-(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}))(\sqrt[3]{-1})+-\sqrt[3]{-1})})
$$

Comment: How do you know you have a mistake?

Comment: because it seems really off.

Comment: The poles are the four complex sixth roots of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

- Starting from the second line, the cosine is the real part, not the imaginary of $e^{i2\pi x}$.
- Then, which one is your **closed** contour? Do you draw the semicircle in the upper half of the complex plane, or in the lower?.
- Also, in that case, what's happening to the integral from $-R$ to $0$?
- If you have a semicircle, you might capture only one of the poles inside.

**EDIT**

Based on your second attempt, here are some suggestions:

- Starting at the beginning, $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac12\Re\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi xi}}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$ If you use instead $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R...$, you will notice that for your integral the sine part is $0$, which is the imaginary part, so you don't need to take the real part.
- The notation $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ is confusing. Use $e^{i\pi/3}$ instead. Alternatively, this is $\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt 3}2$.
- The above notation (especially the one with the exponential) allows you to quickly determine which poles are inside your contour
- The above notation will also allow you to simplify your final expression

Comment: thank you! 
regarding the 2nd comment why half a circle and not a full circle?

Comment: if you can show a full solution I'll be delighted .

Comment: Because a full circle does not contain, as part of the contour, the real line

Comment: so why a half a circle and not a quarter of a circle? as we begin with 0 and not -R

Comment: Because then you need to calculate the integral on the imaginary axis. But your function is even in $x$, so the integral should be easy to express

Comment: can you show me a full solution? I don't understand why is it bad that the path will run within the imaginary path?

Comment: It is not bad conceptually. The integral over the close contour is equal to the sum of the residues. You write the integral over the close contour as the sum of several pieces. If you use a quarter circular sector, the integral over the real axis is exactly what you are looking for, the integral over the circle at $R\to\infty$ is $0$, but how do you calculate the integral over the imaginary axis? If you write it as the integral over half a circle, then $\int_{-R}^0=\int_0^R=\frac12\int_{-R}^R$. Then the integral over the upper part is $0$. So $2\int_0^R+0=2\pi i\sum res(f, z_i)$

Comment: Okay I tried another time, may I have your review?

Comment: I will edit my answer with the comments